# $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2a^2+3bc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{2b^2+3ca}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{2c^2+3ab}} \le \sqrt{ab+bc+ca}$

Tags: inequality, problem-solving, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $a+b+c=3$.Prove that
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{2a^2+3bc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{2b^2+3ca}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{2c^2+3ab}} \le \sqrt{ab+bc+ca}.$$

By C-S we need proof
$$4(a+b+c)^2[\frac{a}{(2a^2+3bc)(4a+b+7c)}+\frac{b}{(2b^2+3ca)(4b+c+7a)}+\frac{c}{(2c^2+3ab)(4c+a+7b)}]-ab-bc-ca \le 0$$
Please try to give an analytical solution rather than a graphical computer oriented one. How to proceed with the working?

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this inequality?  What's the motivation?  Can you credit the original source?  Why is this inequality relevant and useful to future users of this site?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I think this problem is wrong.

Put $a=2.5$, $b=0.5$, $c=0$.